# search for specific repeats using python

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

an example of the input file:

```
1  AAcgGGGGGGtacctgt    yes
2  TTcccccctgtAAcgta   no
3  tcgAAAAaatacgacc     no
4  AAcgtataatacctgt   no
...
```

I want to write a program to scan each sequence and check for monomeric nucleotide repeats (mnr)

example output:

```
1,AAcgGGGGGGtacctgt,yes
2,TTcccccctgtAAcgta,no
```

Definition: monomeric nucleotides are: repeats of A,T,C,G(it is not case sensitive)

I'm looking for in a row would be something like this:
`AAAAaaAAgtc`
or
`gtAAAAAAAAAAc`
or
`aaaaaaAAA`
or
`aaaaaaaaaa`
or
`ccccccccccc`
or
`CCCCCcccCCC`
or...

I tried this regular expressions but does not work:

```
import csv
import re
list=[]
with open('sequences.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
    seq=re.findall(r'[Aa]{6, }','sequences.txt')
    for line in reader:
        if line.__contains__(seq):
            print(list.append(line))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the mnr is a part of a larger string?

Comment: Also clarify if you want more than 8 or more than 6!

Comment: oh sorry for that. yes it is part of the larger string(sequence) and I want more than 6! thanks so much :)

Comment: This site is about programming problems and not for asking others to write code for you. Please provide the code that you have already tried and that did not work the way you expected/wanted it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, well I thought of regular expression and I wrote this..however I know it is not correct:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a compact solution to what you want:

```
import csv
with open('sequences.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        seq_lower = line[1].lower()
        if 'aaaaaa' in seq_lower or 'cccccc' in seq_lower or 'tttttt' in seq_lower or 'gggggg' in seq_lower:
            print(line)
```

Here I assumed that you are only considering mnrs of `a,c,g,t` as youre working with a DNA sequence.

Comment: wow it worked great! just a slight thing is that I needed to change line[1].lower() to 0. however I did not quiet get based on what logic this number keep changing? only because it is in for loop?

Comment: I assumed that the sequence you wanna process is in the second column, so I set line[1].lower(). Yep, with the for loop, line will change to a new line of the file (ore more concisely to a list containing separated strings of the a new line of the file). Now you can accept the answer and vote up if it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Update: A partial solution using regular expressions has since been proposed. Note that the following solution does not work using regex and instead looks for any sequence of any character of length six or more.

Test data:

```
number,sequence,status
1,kjhfklashfkldflkhasdfl,0
2,aaaaaljgkldfkjgldkfjgfldj,0
3,bbbbbbjigdfsjgjg,0
4,ccCccCCcjjfijsdfjsdf,0
5,klsjdflsjdfhdddddjnjlkhngjk,0
6,kjkljfhnlasjkdfheeeeeeejjjeeeeeeeeeekjdkljfleeef,0
7,jhfshffFffFFFFffkljjjj908u89,0
```

Code to find MNR of length 6 or greater:

```py
import csv

def contains_mnr(sequence):
    start_char = "$" # choose a character that is sure not to be in the sequence
    count = 0
    seq_lower = sequence.lower()

    for pos in range(0, len(seq_lower)):
        if seq_lower[pos] == start_char:
            count += 1
        else:
            start_char = seq_lower[pos]
            count = 1
        if count >= 6:
            return True

    return False

with open("input.csv", "r") as input_file:
    with open("output.csv", "w") as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, dialect=csv.unix_dialect())
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, dialect=csv.unix_dialect())
        writer.writerow(reader.fieldnames)

        for row in reader:
            if contains_mnr(row["sequence"]):
                writer.writerow([
                    row["number"],
                    row["sequence"],
                    row["status"]
                ])
```

Note that the CSV dialect may have to be adjusted to the system on which the code is running and the data files are generated.

Output given test data above:

```
"number","sequence","status"
"3","bbbbbbjigdfsjgjg","0"
"4","ccCccCCcjjfijsdfjsdf","0"
"6","kjkljfhnlasjkdfheeeeeeejjjeeeeeeeeeekjdkljfleeef","0"
"7","jhfshffFffFFFFffkljjjj908u89","0"
```

Comment: Cool! Looks like if you´ll get rid of quotation marks, you´ll have the output as specified in question!

Comment: @Etienne Ott Hi Etienne, Tahnks so much for ur solution, first of all did you see my solution? how about that using regex? and for ur solution I dont understand the 'else' part :( and the start_char in my case should be A,C,G or T(each time I have to put each of them right?) and also where should I put my sequence file? Sorry I'm asking easy questions I guess :(

Comment: @Oka could you please clarify which quotation exactly?

Comment: @Nazanin Shambayati  Quotation in the output shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw the update to the question, but I think that using regular expressions is unnecessary for this task. The variable ```start_char``` must not be any character that is expected to appear in the sequence. The method assumes it has already read one instance of that character and if it was any of A,C,G,T then it would incorrectly count the first five characters. The two files specified I called ```input.csv``` and ```output.csv```, but you can of course call them whatever you want. The quotation marks in the output files are there because that's what the CSV dialect specifies.